# Azure Security Center ARM template enabling Windows Secuirty Events

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, securitycenter

I'm creating a ARM template that will enable Azure Security Center for my subscription, but under settings on the subscription in ASC, Security Policy and Data collection, I'm looking to have "Minimal" selected when the template is deployed. I can't find a property for that the same what I was able to find the property for "Auto Provisioning"

```
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Security/autoProvisioningSettings",
        "name": "default",
        "apiVersion": "2017-08-01-preview",
        "properties":{
            "autoProvision": "On"
        }
    },
```

Is there a resource definition for "Windows security events" ?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/securitycenter/autoprovisioningsettings/create#autoprovision) you can only turn it "on" or "off".